# Volatile C/C++ on a multithread app

Tags: c++, multithreading, volatile

I am having a question on the `volatile` usage. I typically try that all the variables shared across threads have the `volatile` keyword to ensure direct memory accesses, and of course protected with mutexes.

**However, is `volatile` really needed if a variable is shared to ensure consistency?**

I explain with an example:

```
Thread1: //(affects it behaviour with the variable)
mymutex.lock();
if(variable)
{
   ...
   variable = false;
}
mymutex.unlock();
```

---

```
Thread2:
mymutex.lock();
variable = true;
mymutex.unlock();
```

In the upper example, `thread2` only writes, and `thread1` reads/writes. Is it possible that the `variable` is cached and the threads do not read the new value? Even though the mutexes are properly set? Do I need `volatile` in this case?

I am asking this because instead of variable I have a `std::vector`, which cannot be volatile. And I am not 100% sure that this approach is safe without the `volatile` keyword.

Thanks.

EDITED: Reformulating the question properly.

Comment: As long as your access to variables is protected by mutex - [you do not have to use `volatile`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172922/does-stdmutex-create-a-fence)

Comment: So, if I derive your comment. Then all the variables accessed inside a mutex/semaphore/CriticalSection, are flushed and visible to other threads after the lock is released?

Comment: @DarkZeros Exactly! That's how it works.

Comment: @DarkZeros Additionally you should use `std::lock_guard`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is 'volatile' needed in this multi-threaded C++ code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612505/is-volatile-needed-in-this-multi-threaded-c-code)

Comment: @DarkZeros If you release lock on one thread, and then trying to read that variable on another *without* locking mutex (suppose you have some other means to ensure the absence of races) then you should use some kind of [`fence`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier). In some environments `volatile` can be used to ensure atomic access, but - it is implementation-dependent, and you should prefer to use ready library with atomics and fences like [`Boost.Atomic`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/atomic.html), or if you have `C++11` - then just use standard stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`volatile` in C++ is not meant for concurrency. It's about whether the compiler is allowed to optimize away reads from a variable or not. It is primarily used for things such as interfacing with hardware via memory mapping.

Unfortunately, this means that even if you do have `volatile` variables, the reads and writes may still access a thread-local store which is not synchronized. Also, an `std::vector` is not thread safe.

So, in either case, you need to synchronize, for example using a `std::mutex` (which you do mention). Now, if this is done, the variables which are protected by that `mutex`do not need to be `volatile`. The `mutex` itself does the synchronization and protects against the type of issues you worry about.

Comment: Correct answer. I'd only like to emphasize which has been already said: "volatile" is not for thread synchronization. If anyone uses volatile for synchronizing threads, the chance that the code will still be incorrect is >90% but will be slower in addition. Ofc there are valid contexts to use volatile in threading, but very few, and usually when implementing low-level synchronization primitives (such as spinlocks).

Comment: Thank you. I found a lot of answers saying "do not use volatile to share data". I obviously not going to share data with volatile only without a mutex. I always use a mutex for sharing. My question is "Is the data flushed without volatile?". This is clearly what I was looking for.

Comment: @DarkZeros All you can ensure is that, if you use proper synchronisation, the effect will be as if the operations from the different threads were interleaved. How they get interleaved and when you see the value written by another thread is beyond your control. However, volatile does not change this, so adding it doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: A spot on answer. I haven't seen this explained so clearly, concisely and correctly before: `volatile` _does have an effect_ in the main, but in this situation it's a completely redundant effect.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612505/is-volatile-needed-in-this-multi-threaded-c-code/3612551#3612551).

Bottom like, don't be clever are use volatile to try guarantee thread safety, use proper