# What exactly is std::atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

I understand that `std::atomic<>` is an atomic object. But atomic to what extent? To my understanding an operation can be atomic. What exactly is meant by making an object atomic? For example if there are two threads concurrently executing the following code:

```
a = a + 12;
```

Then is the entire operation (say `add_twelve_to(int)`) atomic? Or are changes made to the variable atomic (so `operator=()`)?

Comment: You need to use something like `a.fetch_add(12)` if you want an atomic RMW.

Comment: Yep that's what I don't understand. What is meant by making an object atomic. If there was an interface it could simply have been made atomic with a mutex or a monitor.

Comment: @AaryamanSagar it solves an issue of efficiency.  *Mutexes and monitors* carry computational overhead.  Using `std::atomic` lets the standard library decide what's needed to achieve atomicity.

Comment: @AaryamanSagar: `std::atomic<T>` is a type that *allows for* atomic operations. It doesn't magically make your life better, you still have to know what you want to do with it. It's for a very specific use case, and uses of atomic operations (on the object) are generally very subtle and need to be thought of from a non-local perspective. So unless you already know that and why you want atomic operations, the type is probably not of much use for you.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

Each instantiation and full specialization of [std::atomic<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) represents a type that different threads can simultaneously operate on (their instances), without raising undefined behavior:

> Objects of atomic types are the only C++ objects that are free from data races; that is, if one thread writes to an atomic object while another thread reads from it, the behavior is well-defined.
>
> In addition, accesses to atomic objects may establish inter-thread synchronization and order non-atomic memory accesses as specified by `std::memory_order`.

`std::atomic<>` wraps operations that, in pre-C++ 11 times, had to be performed using (for example) [interlocked functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#interlocked_functions) with MSVC or [atomic bultins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) in case of GCC.

Also, `std::atomic<>` gives you more control by allowing various [memory orders](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) that specify synchronization and ordering constraints. If you want to read more about C++ 11 atomics and memory model, these links may be useful:

- [C++ atomics and memory ordering](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2008/12/01/c-atomics-and-memory-ordering/)
- [Comparison: Lockless programming with atomics in C++ 11 vs. mutex and RW-locks](https://www.arangodb.com/2015/02/comparing-atomic-mutex-rwlocks/)
- [C++11 introduced a standardized memory model. What does it mean? And how is it going to affect C++ programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319146/c11-introduced-a-standardized-memory-model-what-does-it-mean-and-how-is-it-g)
- [Concurrency in C++11](https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2013/spring/12300-1/labs/lab6/)

Note that, for typical use cases, you would probably use [overloaded arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) or [another set of them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith2):

```
std::atomic<long> value(0);
value++; //This is an atomic op
value += 5; //And so is this
```

Because operator syntax does not allow you to specify the memory order, these operations will be performed with [`std::memory_order_seq_cst`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), as this is the default order for all atomic operations in C++ 11. It guarantees sequential consistency (total global ordering) between all atomic operations.

In some cases, however, this may not be required (and nothing comes for free), so you may want to use more explicit form:

```
std::atomic<long> value {0};
value.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); // Atomic, but there are no synchronization or ordering constraints
value.fetch_add(5, std::memory_order_release); // Atomic, performs 'release' operation
```

Now, your example:

```
a = a + 12;
```

will not evaluate to a single atomic op: it will result in `a.load()` (which is atomic itself), then addition between this value and `12` and `a.store()` (also atomic) of final result. As I noted earlier, `std::memory_order_seq_cst` will be used here.

However, if you write `a += 12`, it will be an atomic operation (as I noted before) and is roughly equivalent to `a.fetch_add(12, std::memory_order_seq_cst)`.

As for your comment:

> A regular `int` has atomic loads and stores. Whats the point of wrapping it with `atomic<>`?

Your statement is only true for architectures that provide such guarantee of atomicity for stores and/or loads. There are architectures that do not do this. Also, it is usually required that operations must be performed on word-/dword-aligned address to be atomic `std::atomic<>` is something that is guaranteed to be atomic on *every* platform, without additional requirements. Moreover, it allows you to write code like this:

```
void* sharedData = nullptr;
std::atomic<int> ready_flag = 0;

// Thread 1
void produce()
{
    sharedData = generateData();
    ready_flag.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
}

// Thread 2
void consume()
{
    while (ready_flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 0)
    {
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }

    assert(sharedData != nullptr); // will never trigger
    processData(sharedData);
}
```

Note that assertion condition will always be true (and thus, will never trigger), so you can always be sure that data is ready after `while` loop exits. That is because:

- `store()` to the flag is performed after `sharedData` is set (we assume that `generateData()` always returns something useful, in particular, never returns `NULL`) and uses `std::memory_order_release` order:

> `memory_order_release`
>
> A store operation with this memory order performs the **release**
>   operation: no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered
>   **after** this store. **All writes in the current thread are visible in
>   other threads that acquire the same atomic variable**

- `sharedData` is used after `while` loop exits, and thus after `load()` from flag will return a non-zero value. `load()` uses `std::memory_order_acquire` order:

> `std::memory_order_acquire`
>
> A load operation with this memory order performs the **acquire** operation
>   on the affected memory location: no reads or writes in the current
>   thread can be reordered **before** this load. **All writes in other threads
>   that release the same atomic variable are visible in the current
>   thread**.

This gives you precise control over the synchronization and allows you to explicitly specify how your code may/may not/will/will not behave. This would not be possible if only guarantee was the atomicity itself. Especially when it comes to very interesting sync models like the [release-consume ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Consume_ordering).

Comment: Are there actually architectures which do not have atomic loads and stores for primitives like `int`s?

Comment: It's not only about atomicity. it's also about ordering, behaviour in multi-core systems, etc. You may want to read [this article](http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/).

Comment: @AaryamanSagar If I'm not mistaken, even on x86 reads and writes are atomic ONLY if aligned on word boundaries.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I have taken a reference to an atomic type. Could you kindly verify if the following would still guarantee atomic operation on object assignment  https://ideone.com/HpSwqo

Comment: @v.shashenko Any operation smaller than a word isn't "aligned on word boundaries" yet writing a single byte is atomic.

Comment: @curiousguy Doesn't it depend on packing type? Even smaller-than-a-word data can be aligned on word boundaries with gaps between them, unless they're packed tightly, which is controlled during compilation.

Comment: @v.shashenko If "word aligned" means address divisible by the word size then not all naturally aligned smaller-than-a-word objects will be word aligned: half words will be aligned on half word boundary, etc.

Comment: "_no reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered after this store._" Visibly reordered. The impl can still reorder f.ex. operations on "register" local variables (whose address is never accessible by another thread). Some other non atomic writes that can't be legally observed by other threads can also be reordered.

Comment: I'm not clear on why atomic is needed in the producer/consumer example. If `ready_flag` is written to after `sharedData` then how could the consumer end its loop early? Or can a CPU choose to delay writing the value of `sharedData` to the memory shared by the threads until after it has written to `ready_flag`?

Comment: @TimMB Yes, normally, you would have (at least) two situations, where order of execution may be altered: (1) compiler can reorder the instructions (as much as standard allows that) in order to provide better performance of the output code (based on the usage of CPU registers, predictions, etc.) and (2) CPU can execute instructions in a different order to, for example, minimize the number of cache sync points. Ordering constraints provided for `std::atomic` (`std::memory_order`) serves exactly the purpose of limiting the reorders that are allowed to happen.

Comment: What am I missing with the lack of ready_flag being set to 0 in the beginning of the produce method provided that it may be called multiple times?

Comment: generateData() doesn't need release semantics. The facto that the update to flag has release semantics guarantees that other threads see the result before flag is set.

Comment: @anon That would not be correct, neither would it change the scenario modeled on this example (which may not be a production-ready code, you know). If you would like to turn this into a proper producer/consumer model, the producer should block until `ready_flag` is non-zero (meaning: consumer is still processing) and the consumer should reset the flag to 0 after processing (meaning it is done with the processing). This is, of course, assuming a single shared variable. In a typical situation you would use a FIFO queue and a CV so threads can go to sleep as needed (saves CPU clocks).

Answer (score 37):

**`std::atomic` exists because many ISAs have direct hardware support for it**

What the C++ standard says about `std::atomic` has been analyzed in other answers.

So now let's see what `std::atomic` compiles to to get a different kind of insight.

The main takeaway from this experiment is that modern CPUs have direct support for atomic integer operations, for example the LOCK prefix in x86, and `std::atomic` basically exists as a portable interface to those intructions: [What does the "lock" instruction mean in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891067/what-does-the-lock-instruction-mean-in-x86-assembly/56803909#56803909) In aarch64, [LDADD](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0801g/alc1476202791033.html) would be used.

This support allows for faster alternatives to more general methods such as `std::mutex`, which can make more complex multi-instruction sections atomic, at the cost of being slower than `std::atomic` because `std::mutex` it makes `futex` system calls in Linux, which is way slower than the userland instructions emitted by `std::atomic`, see also: [Does std::mutex create a fence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172922/does-stdmutex-create-a-fence)

Let's consider the following multi-threaded program which increments a global variable across multiple threads, with different synchronization mechanisms depending on which preprocessor define is used.

main.cpp

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

size_t niters;

#if STD_ATOMIC
std::atomic_ulong global(0);
#else
uint64_t global = 0;
#endif

void threadMain() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < niters; ++i) {
#if LOCK
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "lock incq %0;"
            : "+m" (global),
              "+g" (i) // to prevent loop unrolling
            :
            :
        );
#else
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            ""
            : "+g" (i) // to prevent he loop from being optimized to a single add
            : "g" (global)
            :
        );
        global++;
#endif
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t nthreads;
    if (argc > 1) {
        nthreads = std::stoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        nthreads = 2;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        niters = std::stoull(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        niters = 10;
    }
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(nthreads);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i)
        threads[i] = std::thread(threadMain);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i)
        threads[i].join();
    uint64_t expect = nthreads * niters;
    std::cout << "expect " << expect << std::endl;
    std::cout << "global " << global << std::endl;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/8244e0529b5f53c929e2d915c3a5c85b5a07e423/userland/cpp/atomic/main.hpp).

Compile, run and disassemble:

```
comon="-ggdb3 -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp -pthread"
g++ -o main_fail.out                    $common
g++ -o main_std_atomic.out -DSTD_ATOMIC $common
g++ -o main_lock.out       -DLOCK       $common

./main_fail.out       4 100000
./main_std_atomic.out 4 100000
./main_lock.out       4 100000

gdb -batch -ex "disassemble threadMain" main_fail.out
gdb -batch -ex "disassemble threadMain" main_std_atomic.out
gdb -batch -ex "disassemble threadMain" main_lock.out
```

Extremely likely "wrong" race condition output for `main_fail.out`:

```
expect 400000
global 100000
```

and deterministic "correct" output of the others:

```
expect 400000
global 400000
```

Disassembly of `main_fail.out`:

```
   0x0000000000002780 <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x0000000000002784 <+4>:     mov    0x29b5(%rip),%rcx        # 0x5140 <niters>
   0x000000000000278b <+11>:    test   %rcx,%rcx
   0x000000000000278e <+14>:    je     0x27b4 <threadMain()+52>
   0x0000000000002790 <+16>:    mov    0x29a1(%rip),%rdx        # 0x5138 <global>
   0x0000000000002797 <+23>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000002799 <+25>:    nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x00000000000027a0 <+32>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x00000000000027a4 <+36>:    add    $0x1,%rdx
   0x00000000000027a8 <+40>:    cmp    %rcx,%rax
   0x00000000000027ab <+43>:    jb     0x27a0 <threadMain()+32>
   0x00000000000027ad <+45>:    mov    %rdx,0x2984(%rip)        # 0x5138 <global>
   0x00000000000027b4 <+52>:    retq
```

Disassembly of `main_std_atomic.out`:

```
   0x0000000000002780 <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x0000000000002784 <+4>:     cmpq   $0x0,0x29b4(%rip)        # 0x5140 <niters>
   0x000000000000278c <+12>:    je     0x27a6 <threadMain()+38>
   0x000000000000278e <+14>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000002790 <+16>:    lock addq $0x1,0x299f(%rip)        # 0x5138 <global>
   0x0000000000002799 <+25>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x000000000000279d <+29>:    cmp    %rax,0x299c(%rip)        # 0x5140 <niters>
   0x00000000000027a4 <+36>:    ja     0x2790 <threadMain()+16>
   0x00000000000027a6 <+38>:    retq
```

Disassembly of `main_lock.out`:

```
Dump of assembler code for function threadMain():
   0x0000000000002780 <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x0000000000002784 <+4>:     cmpq   $0x0,0x29b4(%rip)        # 0x5140 <niters>
   0x000000000000278c <+12>:    je     0x27a5 <threadMain()+37>
   0x000000000000278e <+14>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000002790 <+16>:    lock incq 0x29a0(%rip)        # 0x5138 <global>
   0x0000000000002798 <+24>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x000000000000279c <+28>:    cmp    %rax,0x299d(%rip)        # 0x5140 <niters>
   0x00000000000027a3 <+35>:    ja     0x2790 <threadMain()+16>
   0x00000000000027a5 <+37>:    retq
```

Conclusions:

- the non-atomic version saves the global to a register, and increments the register.

  Therefore, at the end, very likely four writes happen back to global with the same "wrong" value of `100000`.
- `std::atomic` compiles to `lock addq`. The LOCK prefix makes the following `inc` fetch, modify and update memory atomically.
- our explicit inline assembly LOCK prefix compiles to almost the same thing as `std::atomic`, except that our `inc` is used instead of `add`. Not sure why GCC chose `add`, considering that our INC generated a decoding 1 byte smaller.

ARMv8 could use either LDAXR + STLXR or LDADD in newer CPUs: [How do I start threads in plain C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c/52453291#52453291)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.10 AMD64, GCC 9.2.1, Lenovo ThinkPad P51.

Answer (score 22):

> I understand that `std::atomic<>` makes an object atomic.

That's a matter of perspective... you can't apply it to arbitrary objects and have their operations become atomic, but the provided specialisations for (most) integral types and pointers can be used.

> `a = a + 12;`

`std::atomic<>` does not (use template expressions to) simplify this to a single atomic operation, instead the `operator T() const volatile noexcept` member does an atomic `load()` of `a`, then twelve is added, and `operator=(T t) noexcept` does a `store(t)`.

Comment: That was what I wanted to ask. A regular int has atomic loads and stores. Whats the point of wrapping it with atomic<>

Comment: @AaryamanSagar Simply modifying a normal `int` doesn't portably ensure the change is visible from other threads, nor does reading it ensure you see other threads' changes, and some things like `my_int += 3` aren't guaranteed to be done atomically unless you use `std::atomic<>` - they might involve a fetch, then add, then store sequence, wherein some other thread trying to update the same value might come in after the fetch and before the store, and clobber your thread's update.

Comment: "_Simply modifying a normal int doesn't portably ensure the change is visible from other threads_" It's worse than that: any attempt to measure that visibility would result in UB.