# Stop class method running in thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have created a C++ class named Timer, it has 3 methods:

- start()
- stop()
- print()

The `start()` method, enables a flag named `run`, setting its value to `true`.

The `stop()` method, disable the flag, setting its value to `false`.

The `print()` method, executes a `while()` under condition if `run == true`, and print some text sleeping a half second.

---

**Timer.hpp**

```
#ifndef TIMER
#define TIMER 1

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdbool>

#include <unistd.h>

class Timer{
private:
    bool run;

public:
    void start();
    void stop();
    void print();

};

#endif
```

---

**Timer.cpp**

```
#include "Timer.hpp"

void Timer::start(){
    this->run = true;
    this->print();
    return;
}

void Timer::stop(){
    this->run = false;
    return;
}

void Timer::print(){

    int counter = 0;

    while(this->run == true){

        std::cout << counter << std::endl;
        counter++;

        usleep(500000);
    }

    return;
}
```

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include <pthread.h>

#include "Timer.hpp"

void *handler(void *argument){

    ((Timer *) argument)->start();

    return argument;
}

int main(void){

    Timer *timer = new Timer();
    pthread_t timer_thread;
    int mainCounter = 0;

    pthread_create(&timer_thread, NULL, handler, (void *) &timer);

    while(true){

        if(mainCounter == 100){
            std::cout << "Stopping..." << std::endl;
            timer->stop();
        }

        std::cout << " => " << mainCounter << std::endl;
        mainCounter++;

        usleep(50000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**My problem.**

I've created a thread to handle the execution of method `start()`, after I've created a condition inside main thread in which after `mainCounter` get 100 iterations, it executes `timer->stop()`, but it doesn't stop the timer loop.

When `mainCounter` arrives to 100th iteration, it can't stop the loop inside thread.

The instruction to compile is:

```
g++ Timer.cpp -c 
g++ Timer.cpp main.cpp -o main -lpthread
```

The output is:

```
9
 => 90
 => 91
 => 92
 => 93
 => 94
 => 95
 => 96
 => 97
 => 98
 => 99
10
Stopping...
 => 100
 => 101
 => 102
 => 103
 => 104
 => 105
 => 106
 => 107
 => 108
 => 109
11
```

---

## [Try it online!](https://ideone.com/noGz6M)

Comment: If you're going to read and write a variable (such as your `run` boolean variable) from multiple threads, you either need to guard all accesses to that variable with a mutex, or make the variable atomic using `std::atomic`.  Otherwise you're invoking undefined behavior and your program may not do what you expect it to.  (see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978324/what-exactly-is-stdatomic )

Comment: Are you aware that you never exit the loop **in your main thread**?

Comment: @r3musn0x I know i've never exit the main thread, the problem is that i want to stop the loop inside thread.

Comment: @IvanBotero, it just seems from the output you've provided that it's the main thread that continues printing and the secondary thread might have already exited.

Comment: Typo-ish-> `(void *) &timer)` timer's already a pointer. You're passing in a pointer to a pointer and using it (`((Timer *) argument)->start();`) as a mere pointer. Lose the `&`

Comment: You actually stopped worker thread. It's the main thread that continues to run, printing those values.

Comment: @Timmy_A worker thread probably was not stopped. `this` inside `Timer::print` isn't pointing to the same thing as `timer`

Comment: @user4581301 Sure. User has edited his output when I was writing my answer.

Comment: Try to mark run member field with the keyword volatile. But the real error @user4581301 has already described. Using pointer to pointer instead of pointer is the issue. In the worker thread you are modifying different memory, not one that belongs to 'timer' variable. So 'run' is never set to true.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've added an example over ideone.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned by @user4581301, this will solve the problem:

`pthread_create(&timer_thread, NULL, handler, (void *) &timer);`

should be

`pthread_create(&timer_thread, NULL, handler, (void *) timer);`

The problem is that `timer` points to the allocated `Timer` class while `&timer` points somewhere on the stack. While running the thread, you are trying to access the `run` class member, but since `this` is pointing to the stack, you are actually reading an incorrect value.

Other notes: declare `bool run` as `std::atomic_bool run`, or use any mutex mechanism for thread-safety. Also, always delete your allocated variables: `delete timer`.

Comment: Better wording: *points somewhere on the stack* to  *points to `timer` itself, and is already a pointer.* because we know exactly where it points. There is a slightly smarter alternative: Don't use dynamic allocation in the first place: `Timer timer;` Then you can `(void *) &timer`, `timer.stop();`, and not leak `timer` because it wasn't `delete`d. As for the atomic problem, I'm a hack so I'd probably use `volatile sig_atomic_t run;`