# What is the difference between atomic_int and int？

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

Isn't it thread safe when only write and read int in critical section between threads?
So What is the difference between atomic_int and int？
Is 'int' not atomically?

Comment: Also related: [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36685056).  And another close duplicate: [Difference between atomic and int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64506385) which should have come up in your searches.

Comment: If you only read/write something in a critical section, it doesn't need to be atomic.  You have mutual exclusion from locking, so it doesn't matter how many temporary steps are visible.

Comment: Also related, or a good duplicate: [What exactly is std::atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31978324)

Comment: In addition to _atomicity_, atomic types also allow you to control the _ordering of memory operations_, which may be of vital importance. For instance, even though writing to aligned `int` with `mov` instruction is atomic on x64, with `atomic_int`, compilers typically generate `xchg` thanks to the default sequential consistency ordering requirements. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/joGaozPE7.

Comment: "_Is 'int' not atomically?_": `std::atomic` (and `std::atomic_*` types) are the only atomic types. No other type is atomic. But the linked duplicates explain that in much more detail.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::atomic_int` is guaranteed by the standard not to have data races, at all. You don't need to protect it with critical sections.

If you wouldn't have a data race with `int` (such as in a critical section, with a lock that all accesses to the variable respect), then you redundantly wouldn't with `std::atomic_int` either.

You only need `std::atomic<T>` if you want to access a shared variable *without* mutexes or other synchronization to that gives 1 thread at a time exclusive ownership of it.

Comment: But write/read `int` with no lock isn't atomic itself? If no consider of memory sequence or `i++` problems.